# dynamic tableview height based on array count

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

hi fellow developer I want to ask. how can I make a tableview height based on array count, in the first time I use my code. I thought it work because when I tap the arrow It show all the array. but there is a bug, I didn't know it first. that I can scroll up the cell, it means the tableview height is not based on array I want to display. here I show you the ui and my code setup. As you can see, I have a comment in my code that I already try it out some calculation. but it didn't work. can anyone help me

[image: scrolling]

```
    @IBOutlet weak var classTableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var classDownArrowIV: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var classHeightTableView: NSLayoutConstraint!

    @objc func handleClassTap(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        if classContainerHeightConstraint.constant == 75 {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.7, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: {
                self.classDownArrowIV.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "up-chevron")
                let height = CGFloat(self.classes.count) * self.classTableView.rowHeight
                self.classHeightTableView.constant = self.classTableView.contentSize.height
//                self.classHeightTableView.constant = height
//                self.classContainerHeightConstraint.constant = height + 75
                self.classContainerHeightConstraint.constant = self.classTableView.contentSize.height + 75
            })
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding **view.layoutIfNeeded()** after set **self.classContainerHeightConstraint.constant**